# Covariance of two chi-square random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $(X,Y)$ follow bivariate normal distribution where $X,Y$ both follow $N(0,1)$ distribution and $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=c$. Determine the $\operatorname{cov}(X^2,Y^2)$.

I think that the answer will be $c^2$. But I can't make it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 18):

As usual with normal random variables, a direct approach is to realize $(X,Y)$ using some *independent* standard normal random variables, in this case $$(X,Y)=(X,cX+aZ),$$ where $a^2=1-c^2$ and $(X,Z)$ are i.i.d. standard normal. Thus, $$X^2Y^2=c^2X^4+2acZX^3+a^2X^2Z^2.$$
Using $E(X^2)=E(Z^2)=1$, $E(Z)=0$ and $E(X^4)=3$, one gets
$$
E(X^2Y^2)=3c^2+a^2=2c^2+1,
$$
hence
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X^2,Y^2)=E(X^2Y^2)-1=2c^2.
$$
Note that this does not use the joint density of $(X,Y)$, not even the density of a single standard normal random variable $X$, only the first moments of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Given: $(X,Y)$ have joint pdf $f(x,y)$:

[image]

Then, $Cov(X^2,Y^2)$ is:

[image]

where I am using the `Cov` function from the *mathStatica* suite for *Mathematica* to automate the nitty gritties, ... or do this step manually, as per need. [As disclosure, I should perhaps add that I am one of the authors of the package.]